# Command Line Control of Printer Preference Defaults

Tags: powershell, windows-10, printing

I have a set of (Ricoh) printers I want to deploy to my users on Windows 10. (As local TCP/IP Printers). The Computers are not part of any domain. I want to use the locked print feature so that my users jobs are held on the printer and require a code to print. So each users default preferences need to be changed to their unique number. I've written a script using AutoHotKey and Powershell that adds the printers and changes this setting, but I've been unable to find a command line way to change the job type and password field. ATM I am using AutoHotKey to traverse the UI and change the appropriate fields. So My question: Is there a way to set Printing Defaults (And specifically the Job Type and Password) using the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Create a powershell script with the file extension set to .ps1 with the verbiage below.

`$printer = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "Name='HP LaserJet 5Si'"`
`Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $printer -MethodName SetDefaultPrinter`

Run the script.

Comment: And what should I expect to happen when I run this script? It appears that this would change the default printer which is not the question.

Comment: So My question: Is there a way to set Printing Defaults (And specifically the Job Type and Password) using the command line?  --  that was your question at the end of the tldr.  You can use set-credential for the password component.

Comment: Printing Defaults is a subsection of Printer Properties which allows you to set Default Preferences for printing. The Password section I am referring to is a PIN used for print job retrieval. This is probably driver specific, but that is the essence of my question. How to interface with Printer Preferences from command line.

Comment: you can't, it is printer driver specific